# Enable Brotli Compression on cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have an angular 4 production  build deployed on cloudfront. For compression i have enabled gzip compression on the server. I want to enable brotli compression on cloudfront for each requested resource.

I am already sending the gzip br headers as shown in image below:

[image]

How to configure brotli compression on cloudfront?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to handle this on your origin server, CloudFront is gzip only.

If your origin sends a Content-Encoding header CloudFront should not gzip it.

See the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html#compressed-content-custom-origin).

Comment: i think this might actually break the app for clients that dont support brotli as cloudfront does not cache based on Accept-Encoding header, maybe find a CDN that supports brotli?

Comment: I suggest CloudFront + Lambda Edge that will pick the right encoded source (the one supported by the client)

Comment: Or wait until Cloudfront properly supports Brotli.

Comment: It's supported now :) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44754680/enable-brotli-compression-on-cloudfront/63910228#63910228

Answer (score 2):

CloudFront now supports Brotli compression. CloudFront includes 'br' in the normalized 'Accept-Encoding' header before forwarding it to your origin. If your origin does not handle compression, CloudFront can compress cacheable responses at the edge using Brotli.

See the [announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/cloudfront-brotli-compression/) or [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html) for specific details.